# The closed form of the set $Y$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $X=\{A \in M_2(\Bbb{R}): \text{trace}(A)=0\; \text{and}\;\vert a_{ij} \vert\leq 2\} $ and $Y=\{\text{detA}: A \in X\}\subset \Bbb{R}$. Then there exists $\alpha<0$ and $\beta >0$ so that  $Y=[\alpha,\beta]$

How to prove this?

I think $X$ is compact and connected, and $f:A \mapsto \det A$ is continuous, so $Y$ is the continuous image of $X$, and hence $Y$ is  compact and connected!

Is this correct? If not, Can I have a hint?

Comment: In my opinion you're rigth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Identifying $M_2( \mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^4$ you have that $X$ is the intersection of the hypercube $[-2,2]^4$ with the hyperplane given by the vanishing of the trace. Hence $X$ is compact and its image under a continuous map has to be compact as well. Since $X$ is connected, $Y$ is compact and connected, therefore $Y$ is a closed interval.

To prove that $X$ is connected, one can use that it is convex and this follows from $X$ being the intersection of two convex sets.

Comment: I have one doubt: How the left end point of $Y$ is negative?

Comment: The matrix with $0$ in its diagonal and $2$ elsewhere is in $X$ and has determinant $-4$.

Comment: If you take this matrix and change the sign of one entry you'll get a matrix in $X$ whose determinant is $4$.

Comment: In fact, you can show that $Y = [-8,8]$.

Comment: Ok! I understand....Thanks!